# Computing probability that the mean of a random sampling will exceed some N?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let X~Exp($\frac{1}{28}$), and A={$X_1$, $X_2$, ... , $X_{21}$} be a random 21 element sampling of X.

I want to find the exact probability that mean(A) $\geq$ 20.

I know I can use the Central Limit Theorem or bootstrapping to approximate it, but any tips on how I might compute the exact probability? Is it as simple as finding the the pdf of the bootstrap distribution and taking an integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{21} \sum_{i=1}^{21} X_i = \sum_{i=1}^{21} \frac{X_i}{21}$ is the sum of $21$ i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exp}(3/4)$ random variables, so its distribution is $\operatorname{Gamma}(21, 3/4)$. If you have the means to compute the CDF of this distribution, then you can find your answer.

Another approach is to use a Poisson process with rate $3/4$.
\begin{align}
P(\sum_{i=1}^{21}\frac{X_i}{21} \ge 20)
&= P(\text{$21$st arrival happens after time $20$})
\\
&= P(\text{at most $20$ arrivals in time interval $[0,20]$)}
\\
&= e^{-15}\sum_{k=0}^{20} \frac{15^k}{k!}.
\end{align}

Comment: @Did Thank you for fixing my mistake!